# Can you use burn cards in private matches? Do they "Burn"?

Tags: titanfall

Following yesterday's patch, I decided to rummage around the new feature, private matches. (However, due to the lack of online friends to play with, :( , I was unable to actually enter one.)

The Titan and Pilot load outs (and by extension, the Burn Cards) shown on the private match screen are the same (i.e. Change one, change the other.) as the ones on the other menus, which led me to the question(s):

1. Can you use Burn cards in private matches?
2. Does using the Burn cards mean you can't again use them in online multiplayer?

Comment: I wish they would have allowed for a "1 player" private match... It's just so hard to practice on or explore a particular map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I did some research, and here are my findings:

1. Yes, you can use Burn Cards.
2. Yes, they are burned, and then can't be used in multiplayer.